# Getting org.springframework.remoting.RemoteAccessException Could not access JMS invoker queue [QueueName] at random times?

Tags: java, spring, web-services, timeoutexception

I am getting this exception at random times, couldnt detect any specific patterns when this comes up. The occurrences of this exception reduce after sometime by itself. We checked the broker is always running properly so queue seems to be available when this exception comes.

```
org.springframework.remoting.RemoteAccessException: Could not access JMS invoker queue [QueueName]; nested exception is javax.jms.JMSException: edu.emory.mathcs.backport.java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
    at my.data.message.bus.MyJmsInvoker.convertJmsInvokerAccessException(MyJmsInvoker.java:92)
    at org.springframework.jms.remoting.JmsInvokerClientInterceptor.invoke(JmsInvokerClientInterceptor.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy203.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor868.invoke(Unknown Source)
```

I am new to Java EE, if someone has faced this and know the reason/fix for this please help.